# XRDP and Hyper-V running on Windows 8 Enterprise

Tags: 12.04, xrdp, hyper-v

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.2 as a Hyper-V client and it runs perfectly. But because Hyper-V only allows a small window (800x600) which can not be changed (as far as I know) I've been trying to use XRDP to launch it into a full screen. It does work or at least to a point, as soon as I launch the Home Folder in Ubuntu XRDP terminates. My Ubuntu client as latest updates and I have used XRDP  with success to access a stand alone Ubuntu machine.

Any thoughts about the issue or alternate solution that works well with Windows 8 Enterprise?

Answer (score 0):

There are probably better ways, but to modify display resolution minimum, this worked for me (setting my resolution to the current max of the synthetic display driver which is 1920x1080):

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub/cfgset
```

Edit the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` to include:

```
quiet splash video=hyperv_fb:1920x1080
```

Exit and save and then run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Then restart your virtual machine.